# How make 3des-cbc IV?

Tags: c++, ssh

i working now on realization of SSH protocol in C ++. I deal with cbc encryption mode. I understood that initial vector's initialization for first block is calculated from a hash of certain data, vector's initialization for the next blocks - it's previous block of ciphertext. It works only for the first packet, in the second packet is impossible to decrypt the first block. Maybe because the last block of ciphertext is comprised of 4 bytes? How is calculate the initial IV for the second package?

Comment: Not sure how 3des is related to the question but 3DES should not be used in new work, it has been superseded by AES.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia explains the CBC quite well:

[image]

The initiation vector for the second bloc is the first block of ciphertext

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [RFC 4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253):

> The encrypted data in all packets sent in one direction SHOULD be
> considered a single data stream.  For example, initialization vectors
> SHOULD be passed from the end of one packet to the beginning of the
> next packet.

And although it's a "SHOULD" I couldn't find any deviation from this, so your second packet should use the last block from the first packet as an IV.